# Selenium Webdriver exucatable_path

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

When I am passing fully qualified path for the executable_path the Chrome() method able to locate the driver but when I am creating a directory(drivers) inside the project in pycharm and passing as

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="../drivers/chromedriver")
```

then Chrome() method fails to locate.

According to me, error reason would be: 
1) chromedriver copied into the local directory is not supporting.(Getting a question mark on the copied chromedriver executable file)

2) Proper path is not passed

Image Of My Structure & Error Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

Then:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver    

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Chrome' .. getting this error

Comment: @SuperbSushant You did Not Import webdriver

Comment: @SuperbSushant Answer Updated

Comment: @SuperbSushant Try Now!

Answer (score 0):

When using a relative path, it needs to include the `r` to specify it's raw. Also, include the `.exe` in the path for the driver.

For example,

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'../drivers/chromedriver.exe')#Use single quotation mark
```

Apply the same changes to yours and it should solve your problem.

Comment: Hey, I am using ubuntu and it doesn't support exe. I have tried using r and single quote but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try To add one dot

Try This:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./driver/chromedriver")
```

Answer (score 0):

dealing with paths can be a bit tricky, i always use a lib

```
import pathlib
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=str(pathlib.Path().absolute().parent.joinpath('drivers').joinpath('chromedriver'))))
```

hope it helps.